# jQuery Panels - Weird Content Effect

Tags: jquery, toggle, jquery-animate, slide

I am getting a very weird jQuery effect on a website I am building.

http://www.real-visual.com/site/Technology/

On this page, in the left panel, you will see 4 orange links.  If you click one, it slides open a content panel.  Then, if you click a different orange link, it slides closed the first panel and slides open the second one.

However, you will notice a weird effect where, when a slide is sliding closed, the content inside it changes.

Here is an example of the jQuery code that powers these slides:

```
$("#panel-2-button").click(function() {
    if ($('.togglepanel').is(':visible')) { $(".togglepanel").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); }
    $("#content-inner-panel-2").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 
});
$("#panel-2-button-medium").click(function() {
    if ($('.togglepanel').is(':visible')) { $(".togglepanel").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); }
    $("#content-inner-panel-2-medium").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
$("#panel-2-button-large").click(function() {
    if ($('.togglepanel').is(':visible')) { $(".togglepanel").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); }
    $("#content-inner-panel-2-large").toggle("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);

});
```

And here is an example of the HTML:

```
<div id="content-inner-panel-2-medium" class="togglepanel">
    <h1>Microsoft Kinect</h1>
    <p>Text Here</p>
    <div id="panel-2-close-medium"></div>
</div>

 <div id="content-inner-panel-3-medium" class="togglepanel">
    <h1>Large Screen & Immersive</h1>
    <p>Text Here</p>
    <div id="panel-3-close-medium"></div>
 </div>

  <div id="content-inner-panel-4-medium" class="togglepanel">
    <h1>Mobile Phones & Tablets</h1>
    <p>Text Here</p>
    <div id="panel-4-close-medium"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="content-inner-panel-5-medium" class="togglepanel">
    <h1>Games Controllers & Remotes</h1>
    <p>Text Here</p>
    <div id="panel-5-close-medium"></div>
  </div>
```

Does anyone know why the weird content-switcharound bug is occuring when a slide closes and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the line:

```
if ($('.togglepanel').is(':visible')) { $(".togglepanel").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); }
```

specifically:

```
$(".togglepanel").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
```

That line hides the first element in the .togglepanel that it finds (which would be the Kinect one) and hides that. You need to find the id of the visible .togglepanel and hide that id, not just class:

```
var visiblepanel = 'none';
$('.togglepanel').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
        visiblepanel = $(this).attr('id');
    }
});
if (visiblepanel != 'none'){ $(visiblepanel).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); }
```

that last line might need to prepend the # symbol like so:

```
if (visiblepanel != 'none'){ $('#' + visiblepanel).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); }
```

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in the code you provided, on the 2nd line.   Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: There's a missing . before the each

Comment: Okay, the code functions now, however, previously, the slides were opening and closing smoothly using the "slide" effect, and now in some cases they are just appearing or disappearing.  You can look on the page I linked in my original post above to see an example of this.   Why has the code broken the slide effects?

Comment: A couple different issues could be the culprit (maybe even a combination of these): 1) After checking if visiblepanel != 'none', add a callback function to hide() that starts the slideout, after the hide has completed, on false you would just do an immediate slideout.  2) .toggle has direction "left", shouldn't that be "right"? 3) There is a small chance that you need to add stop() function to your animations to deal with this issue, although this is a good function to add to mouse driven animations in any case.